# Using the content of a variable returned by DataTables in another part of the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I use the "DeviceID" in the "columns:" in another part of the script. I have tried all manner of things like re positioning some of the code but no matter what I do I can't get it to work.

I need to use the "DeviceID" as a variable in

```
"url: 'get_wayfinder_offline_status.php', data: { DeviceID: deviceid },"
```

Look at `<< USE THIS IN PART MARKED "HERE"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#WayFinderStatusTable').DataTable({
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    bInfo: false,
    responsive: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    scrollX: false,
    pageResize: true,
    ajax: {
      url: 'check_wayfinder_status.php',
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [{
        data: 'DisplayDescription',
        "sWidth": "100%"
      },
      {
        data: 'DeviceName',
        "visible": false
      },
      {
        data: 'MessageCount',
        "visible": false
      },
      {
        data: 'BoardOverride',
        "visible": false
      },
      {
        data: 'DeviceID',
        "visible": false
      }, // << USE THIS IN PART MAKED "HERE"
    ],
    rowCallback: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      if (data.MessageCount == 2) {
        $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('WayFinderStatusTableOn HeaderStatusWayfinderRedTextBlink');
      } else if (data.BoardOverride == 1) {
        $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('WayFinderStatusTableOverrideOn ');
        $('#WayFinderStatusTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
          var hotelid = "<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid'];?>";
          var data = table.row(this).data();
          var deviceid = data.DeviceID;
          console.log("DEVICE ID", deviceid);
          $.ajax({
            url: 'get_wayfinder_override_status.php',
            data: {
              DeviceID: deviceid
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
              var result = JSON.stringify(data);
              result = JSON.parse(result);
              if (result.length > 0) {
                console.log("BoardName", result);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderRecordID').val(result[0]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderBoardName').val(result[1]);
                var testimage = result[2];
                console.log("TEST IMAGE", testimage);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderImage').val(result[2]);
                var imagepath = '../../../../conf/conf_images/override/' + hotelid + '/' + result[2];
                $("#EditOverrideWayfinderLookUpCompanyImage").attr("src", imagepath);
                $("#EditOverrideWayfinderImagePreview").attr("src", imagepath);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderRoomFromDate').val(result[3]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderRoomFromTimeH').val(result[4]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderRoomFromTimeM').val(result[5]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderRoomToDate').val(result[6]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderRoomToTimeH').val(result[7]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderRoomToTimeM').val(result[8]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderPromotionName').val(result[9]);
                $('#EditOverrideWayfinderHardwareID').val(result[10]);
                $('#edit_wayfinder_override_data_modal').modal('show');
              }
            }
          });
        });
      } else if (data.BoardOverride == "") {
        $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('WayFinderStatusTableOff');
      }
    },
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.WayFinderStatusTableOff', function(e) {
    $('#wayfinder_override_data_modal').modal('show');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.WayFinderStatusTableOn', function(e) {
    console.log("OFFLINE CLICKED");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'get_wayfinder_offline_status.php',
      data: {
        DeviceID: deviceid //<<HERE
      },
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
        var result = JSON.stringify(data);
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
          // DO SOMETHING
        }
      }
    });
    $('#offline_data_modal').modal('show');
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#WayFinderStatusTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
  }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: I think you really mean you want to extract the specific Device ID from a clicked row, is that right? Asking to use the DeviceID from the "columns" section makes no sense...that's just a string defining the label of the column heading.

Comment: @ ADyson  Yes that's right,  want to extract the specific Device ID from a clicked row. But how?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html looks like it gives you the general idea. Did you search much? I don't use DataTables but I googled "datatables row click" and that was about the second result...it shows how you can get the data from the clicked row.

Comment: @ADyson I did try that approach but is errors with "undefined". I have searched and read so many documents and posts but nothing I try works.

Comment: show precisely what you tried, please

Answer (score 1):

Based on structure of your datatables and column, clicked on a row the deviceId is find by using the method `table.row( this ).data();` and next find the right index of the data.

```
$('#WayFinderStatusTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
   const data = table.row( this ).data();
   const deviceId = data[4];
   alert(deviceId + ' -> deviceid');
});
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your reply. I will work with your code and let you know how I get on. Again, thanks.

Comment: @DCJones this is pretty much identical to the code I linked to in the documentation and which you claimed didn't work for you...

Comment: @ADyson perhaps the problem was in the indexes of the datatables to be accessed...

Comment: @ADyson Hi I didn't claim the code didn't work, it didn't work. It's still not working correctly but I will post when I have a solution. Many thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @DCJones to clarify, when I said "claim" what I meant was you didn't show us exactly how you implemented it and you didn't explain exactly what the error was. So it was just a statement without evidence. No offence or doubt intended. I'm sure it's true that whatever you did didn't work correctly, but we don't know for sure if you implemented the idea correctly. So if you were to show us you exact version we could help you fix it rather than just giving general examples of the principle

Comment: @ADyson  Your right, I do need to explain the issue with more detail. Still working on the code.